# Can't Stop Simultaneous Step Execution in Shell Script That Opens jEdit GUI Windows

Tags: shell-script, xfce

```
#!/bin/sh
jedit file.txt
zenity --info
...several more more commands...
exit
```

Expected behavior: I command the script (in this case, via a keyboard shortcut). A **jEdit** window then opens on my **Xfce4** desktop, displaying the contents of **file.txt**. I perform some text manipulation within same and then manually close said **jEdit** window. Next, the commanded **Zenity** window appears, as expected. I close same manually and the next step of the script executes...and I experience joy and contentment.

However, if, for some reason I've *already got* an unrelated **jEdit** window open on the desktop when I command the script (again, via a keyboard shortcut), here's what now happens: After said script is so commanded, the expected **jEdit** window (the one displaying the contents of **file.txt**) opens, *along with* the **Zenity** window (note that, in this case, said **Zenity** window opens *before* the **jEdit** window is manually closed by me).  This is undesired behavior...and I experience rage and despair.

I have tried many things, including the `wait` command and appending the `terminal` line with  `&&`. I've also attempted trapping. Nothing is working for me.

What is causing this to happen and how can I remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jedit -noserver`. From the [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/jedit.1.html):

```
-background
      Run jEdit in background mode. In background mode, the  edit  server  will  continue
      listening  for  client  connections  even after all views are closed. Has no effect
      when connecting to another instance via the edit server.
-nobackground
      Disable background mode. This is the default. Has  no  effect  when  connecting  to
      another instance via the edit server.
...
-server
      Store  the  server  port  info  in  the  file  named  "server"  inside the settings
      directory. This is the default.
...
-noserver
      Do not attempt to connect to a running edit server, and does not start one either.
```